# Which branch changes stay when I delete .git folder

Tags: git

I've been deleting the .git folder every time I want to stop tracking a git project and right now I'm curious as to which changes stay when I delete the .git folder. Let's say I clone a repository. It comes with master branch by default. I now change into a branch called develop. The master branch has some changes not in the develop branch. If I then delete the .git folder while I'm in the develop branch, what changes stay? Is it the changes in the default repository(master) or branch I was in before deleting the folder?

Comment: In addition to `.git/` there are also git-related files scattered over working directory, most notable `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes`. If you don't plan to create a new git repository with this working directory you probably would want to remote these files too.

Answer (score 4):

When you remove the `.git` folder, all that remains is your "working [copy/tree/directory]". This is the currently checked out branch, plus the changes you made to the files in there.

See also:

- [How do I remove Git tracking from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754152/how-do-i-remove-git-tracking-from-a-project)
- [Git: Where exactly is the "working directory"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201342/git-where-exactly-is-the-working-directory)
- [Git Manual: Git Basics, The Three States](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#The-Three-States)